# Object instance exception thrown when bound collection of carousel view is cleared

Tags: carousel, xamarin.forms

I have a carousel view who's itemsource property is set in Xaml. When clearing the bound collection from within the view model I get an object instance exception thrown. But on further inspection it's not the collection which is null, it's the clear method itself which is indicated as an "unknown member". The carousel page works fine on Android an Windows phone, but on iOS I receive this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on iPhone the lifetime of the carousel view is disposed when navigating away from the view. When re-visiting the view the carousel view would throw all sorts of errors because it had been disposed. On Windows Phone and Android there is no such problem. I would have been handy if in the documentation it would state that the lifetime of the control would be disposed when navigating away from the view.

To solve the problem I simply new'd up the view and view model every time they're re-visited, in other words making their lifetime transient.

Comment: Woops made a mistake - this article is for Carousel Page not Carousel View !